# Restore an HP Recovery Manager save on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, data-recovery, hp

I had a few problems on my HP Pavilion 15 running Windows 8 and decided to install Ubuntu instead. In order to save my files, I did a save using HP Recovery Manager. Is there a way I could restore those files on Ubuntu 14.04? Most of them are .dll and .swm.

Thanks in advance,

MM